# What does '+ +' mean in python?

Tags: python

I'm reading a python book. It's explaining for loops and range() function.

But I don't understand what does '+ and +' mean.

```
for i in range(7):
    print('hello('+str(i)+')')
```

Comment: Hi, the line is concatenating three strings together: `'hello'`, `str(i)`, and `')'`. The string literals are surrounded by quotes.

Comment: Doesn't your book explain what it's doing?

Comment: that mean paste together .

Comment: I understand your confusion. People still haven't learnt how to use spaces when writing code and it's unfortunate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it should read as:

```
string_a + string_b + string_c
```

It is not about "+ xxx +".

It literally concatenate string_a, string_b and string_c together albeit it is not pythonic.

A more pythonic way may be:

```
print( "hello({my_var})".format(my_var=i) )
```